# PHP code to use the markdown parser

Tags: php, markdown, markitup

I am attempting to use MarkItUp and PHP Markdown Parser. But I am don't know how to invoke the parser in the preview.php file.

My preview.php is invoked and correct form data is sent by inspect the network call. But instead of parsed text only the content of the file is listed in the preview window.

Following is the content of my preview.php

```
include_once "markdown.php";
$html=Markdown($_POST['data']);
echo htmlentities($html);
```

markdown.php is placed at the same level as preview.php.
Also I verified that my Apache does support php. `http://localhost/test.php` renders properly where test.php is simply `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

What's wrong with my preview.php?

Comment: Does any other PHP code work on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's *exactly* the content of preview.php, you're missing a `<?php` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just missing an opening `<?php` before your PHP code...‽